# Unable to Upgrade Dart SDK from 2.18.7 to 2.19.0 using Homebrew

Tags: dart, homebrew

I am trying to upgrade my Dart SDK from 2.18.7 to 2.19.0 using homebrew formula `brew upgrade dart`.

However, the command always returns the same result

```
Warning: dart-lang/dart/dart 2.18.7 already installed.

brew info dart command shows:
```

```
==> dart-lang/dart/dart: stable 2.18.7, HEAD
SDK
https://dart.dev
Conflicts with:
  dart-beta (because dart-beta ships the same binaries)
/usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.18.7 (921 files, 497MB) *
  Built from source on 2023-01-29 at 02:33:36
From: https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/blob/HEAD/Formula/dart.rb
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Please note the path to the Dart SDK:
  /usr/local/opt/dart/libexec
```

I also have tried:

```
brew uinstall dart<br>
brew install dart<br>
brew upgrade dart
brew upgrade dart --devel --force
resulting `Error: invalid option: --devel`
```

Please, kindly suggest me any other solutions that could help.

Comment: 2.19.0 isn't in the beta list.  It's in stable!  Yes, stable is now greater than beta, at least for now.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm also stuck on the same issue

Answer (score 2):

1. `brew uninstall dart`
2. `brew install dart-sdk`

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred as the homebrew formula for dart 2.18.7 is missing in the homebrew core formula commit history:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula/dart-sdk.rb

However, my dart version upgraded to 2.18.7 from 2.18.6 by an unintentional brew upgrade command resulting the issue.